# Converting DD-MON-YY to YYYY-MM-DD in informatica

Tags: date, mapping, type-conversion, informatica

I have a date column in a flat file with a format of `DD-Mon-YY` which needs to be converted to `YYYY-MM-DD`. This is the expression which I have used in the expression transformation

```
IIF(IS_DATE(Event_Date,'DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE(Event_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),NULL)
```

There's an error saying invalid string format due to the reason that there's no century (26-Sep-16) information in the input date.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as simple function provided below,

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Event_Date,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

To know more on informatica, have fun with this blog,
http://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/

Comment: Im not getting the whole year part, the string 26-sep-16 is to be converted to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Which is your target. Its flat file or database?

Comment: Target is a teradata table, i am converting is the same expression which you have mentioned, the Format 26-Sep-16 is not able retrieve the year information since only 16 is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing TO_DATE, you need to specify the Input Date Format, not output date format.

```
IIF(IS_DATE(Event_Date,'DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE(Event_Date,'DD-MON-YY'),NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert it to date telling PowerCenter what's the string format [`TO_DATE(Event_Date, 'DD-MON-YY')`]. Then you convert it to string with a desired format [`TO_CHAR( yourDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`]. Putting it all together, try:

`IIF(IS_DATE(Event_Date,'DD-MON-YY'), 
    TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(Event_Date, 'DD-MON-YY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
    NULL)`

Comment: Hi Maciejg, It worked. However, i had to convert the whole to_char part to to_date since my target column is of date data type. Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Glad it worked. But if you need it as date, then you could GET RID of TO_CHAR rather than adding TO_DATE on top of it. TO_CHARs input is date in the first place.
The thin is you've specified you need it as YYYY-MM-DD. This, and any other formatting, is applicable to strings only. A date is just a date and as such has no format.